# time complexity of creating of binary tree

Tags: java, time-complexity, binary-tree

There is a method that builds a binary tree in which there are N full levels and on
each level I there are two nodes whose information parts are equal to I. What is the time complexity depending on the number of levels of the tree built?

```
private SimpleTreeNode fromNDigitToNode(int x,int k) throws Exception {
        IndexWrapper iw = new IndexWrapper();
        T parentValue = readValue((k-x+1)+"",iw);
        SimpleTreeNode parentNode = new SimpleTreeNode(parentValue);
        SimpleTreeNode leftNode = new SimpleTreeNode(parentValue);
        SimpleTreeNode rightNode = new SimpleTreeNode(parentValue);
        if(x<=1)return parentNode;
        int z = --x;
            parentNode.left = fromNDigitToNode(z,k);
            parentNode.right = fromNDigitToNode(z,k);

        return parentNode;
    }
```

```
public void fromNDigit(String Ndigit) throws Exception{
        int digit = Integer.parseInt(Ndigit);

        IndexWrapper iw = new IndexWrapper();
        SimpleTreeNode root = fromNDigitToNode(digit,digit);

        this.root = root;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: The two functions posted do not interact at all.

Comment: sorry. my mistake. code is edited

Comment: So, exactly 2^N items?  Are they ordered when you start?

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is flawed. You create leftNode and rightNode, but you don't use them. Furthermore, both parentNode.left and parentNode.right are created with the same parameters. Is that correct?

I have no idea what your IndexWrapper is for and what readValue() does.

And the biggest problem: this never stops. You don't check (for instance) if x < 0. So you call it with x=1. You then recurse twice, calling it with x=0, then x=-1, and repeat forever.

So I'd say this is Order(forever).

Might I suggest you actually get your code to work, test it, and THEN figure out the complexity.